# How to install MySQL 5.6 on Debian (wheezy or squeeze) and make it work

Tags: mysql, debian

How to install MySQL 5.6 on Debian (wheezy or squeeze)?
The package is on mysql site but what's next?

Thanks for first answers. I actually installed it but it won't work.

Comment: you need 5.6? if not, use the Debian packaged version `apt-get install mysql-server` which is 5.5 now on Wheezy

Comment: yes, of course I need 5.6

Comment: then take a look at Jotschi's answer

Answer (score 2):

The deb package from oracle is not very well done. It lacks the dependency fields, init scripts and the automatic installation.

Take a look at this answer:

[How to install Mysql 5.6 on Debian 7 wheezy](https://serverfault.com/questions/516190/how-to-install-mysql-5-6-on-debian-7-wheezy/516543#516543)

Answer (score 0):

Once you've downloaded the file,use the terminal to navigate to where you downloaded the file and run:

```
dpkg -i mysql-5.6.7-rc-debian6.0-x86_64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dpkg -i package.name.deb
```

+ For MySQL you need to install libaio1 as far as i remember.

```
apt-get install libaio1
```